# jquery repeat animation

Tags: jquery

This code seems to break the remainder of my code?

```
function sam() {
    $("#animate").children("#box")
        .animate({
        left: '+=1100'},8000, 'linear', function() {
            $("#animate").children("#box").css("left", "0");
            sam();
        });
}

setInterval(sam());
```

Sorry about the short response but I kept getting blocked by a stupid quality message

Comment: What does "break the remainder of my code" mean?

Comment: It just stops other parts of my code from working in firefox only?

Answer (score 8):

Try to change

```
setInterval(sam());
```

to

```
setInterval(function(){
    sam()
}, 1000);
```

which will trigger sam() every second.Your usage of setInterval is wrong

Also, delete `sam()` call in `sam()` function.

So final code:

```
function sam() {
    $("#animate").children("#box")
        .animate({
        left: '+=1100'},8000, 'linear', function() {
            $("#animate").children("#box").css("left", "0");
        });
}

setInterval(function(){
    sam()
}, 1000);
```

Comment: also no need to call sam() recursively since setInterval will take care of repeated execution

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` needs a second parameter for how often you are going to run the code sam(). but I dont know if you want that, it seems to do that anyway.

```
function sam() {
    $("#animate").children("#box")
        .animate({
            left: '+=1100'},8000, 'linear', function() {
            $("#animate").children("#box").css("left", "0");
            sam();
        });
}

sam();
```

should be enought if you want to repeat the animation over and over again, or use setTimeout instead of setInterval.

Set interval will relaunch the code, even if the first run isnt finished, your animation takes 8 seconds, if you say run sam() every 2 second for example you will get a very, very bad result because the codes takes more then 2 seconds to run and you also said that it should rerun itself. I would not use `setInterval` at all.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/tG7Gm/2/

Comment: seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/tG7Gm/1/ how does your markup look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the finished-animation callback to start a new animation. Could you clarify if you want the animation to start when the first one is finished, or just have endless animations on top of each other?

Comment: I want the animation to repeat constantly

Comment: What is the finished animation callback?

Comment: Sorry it took so long. Read here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ 2nd example under Basic usage.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `()` from where you're passing `sam` as the callback. You want to pass the function, not the result of it.

```
var sam = function() { // Changed this to show functions are variables
    $("#animate").children("#box")
        .animate({
        left: '+=1100'},8000, 'linear', function() { // Not sure about +=
            $("#animate").children("#box").css("left", "0");
            sam; // Pass the variable, not the result of the function
        });
};
sam(); // Call the function the first time.
```

However, I notice that `#box` is an id. So I've extrapolated what I think you want to do and come up with this demo:

```js
var sam = function() { // Changed this to show functions are variables
    $("#box").animate({left: $("#animate").width() + 'px'}, 1000, 'linear')
             .animate({left: '-' + $("#box").width() + 'px'}, 0, 'linear', sam);
};
sam(); // Call the function the first time.
```

```css
#animate {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animate">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Or JsFiddle if you prefer: http://jsfiddle.net/Gisleburt/tn8j7w8p/1/